# How to export my bookmarks via CLI in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line

Is there any way how to export all bookmarks from Google Chrome using my CLI?

Comment: What OS and what CLI?

Comment: @EBGreen I have this same question.  My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.  Any commandline that will produce each bookmark element would be great, whether it's java, python, perl, bash, or a collection of tools.  I have been trying to extact the json file so that I can have each bookmark.  But I can't get to all the individual objects because of the much embedding of folders and arrays.  The purpose of having a cli would be so that I can import the elements into my own database for organizing.

Answer (score 15):

Chrome stores bookmarks in you [profile directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md), in the `Bookmarks` file, which is in JSON format

Comment: chrome stable: file: /home/<USER>/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks

Comment: does modifying those bookmarks on the harddrive cause them to sync to google on next launch, or would chrome overwrite the file with the cloud version (such as if a bookmark were deleted)?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a neat thing on macosx :

```
BOOKMARKS=/Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks.bak

# method 1
python test.py $BOOKMARKS

# pipe example
# shuffle tty's for pdb to work

cat $BOOKMARKS | python test.py
```

test.py :

```
import json
import fileinput
from io import BytesIO

bookmarks = BytesIO()
for line in fileinput.input():
    bookmarks.write(line.encode('utf-8'))
bookmarks.seek(0)
bakmarks = json.loads(bookmarks.read())
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: I'm writing console bookmark manager, which gets bookmarks from Chromium. Your answer helped me to find bookmark file and parse in in JSON! On BSD path to bookmarks is $HOME/.config/chromium/Default/Bookmarks.bak

Comment: Try with `jq`: `cat /Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks.bak | jq .`

Answer (score 0):

*(With tips from above answers, I found a simple solution that support all major OS, via shell shortcut.)*

---

### Backup chrome bookmark - via command line

**Steps:**

- `vi ~/.bashrc`
- Add lines:

  ```
  CHROME_BOOKMARK="$HOME/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Bookmarks"
  alias bmcsync='cp "$CHROME_BOOKMARK" "/d/someRepo/b-1 backup/5-1 bookmark/"'
  ```
- Save
- `source ~/.bashrc`
- Then could use command `bmcsync` to copy the bookmark to somewhere else *(bmc means bookmark of chrome)*.

**Where to use this:**

- Shell terminal, in `Linux` / `Mac`.
- Git bash, for `Windows`.

---

### Restore chrome bookmark - from `Bookmarks` file

**Refer:**
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/UHLBRHIaTSI

**Steps:**

- Close chrome.
- Copy `Bookmarks` file back to original place you copy it from, and replace the current one.
- Start chrome.
- Check bookmark again.

**Tips:**

- When you copy & replace `Bookmarks` file, it will replace, **not** merge.
  So, be careful.
- There is also a `Bookmarks.bak` file, seems not useful in backup & restore in this case, so just ignore it.

Comment: would chrome pickup the overwritten file, or re-overwrite it with the cloud version? what about firefox?

Comment: if u override the file, chrome will pick up it; didn't test about firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The question is `how to export bookmarks from [shell]`, with my assumption being mac osx, though we can easily expand to any posix'ish shell. The OP didn't ask how to do it in python, or to modify the interactive shell environment, `.bashrc`, every time they launch a new shell, for a recovery process that is executed every so often and (should) never be done manually.

"backup" and "restore" are fairly complex ways to describe copying a file to and from a path.

Review bookmark path and get current checksum

```sh
$ echo $path
/Users/christian/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome
$ ls -lh "$path/Default/Bookmarks"
-rw------- 1 christian staff 27K Aug  8 10:01 '/Users/christian/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks'
$ <"$path/Default/Bookmarks" jq -r .checksum
e9778031e907cf8d2d196be3319ac24d
```

"backup" bookmarks and sanity check operation

```sh
~ $ <"$path/Default/Bookmarks" jq -re .checksum | xargs -rI% -- cp -v "$path/Default/Bookmarks" /tmp/bookmarks/%.json
'/Users/christian/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks' -> '/tmp/bookmarks/e9778031e907cf8d2d196be3319ac24d.json'
~ $ </tmp/bookmarks/e9778031e907cf8d2d196be3319ac24d.json jq .checksum
"e9778031e907cf8d2d196be3319ac24d"
```

"restore" bookmarks

```sh
~ $ cp -v /tmp/bookmarks/e9778031e907cf8d2d196be3319ac24d.json "$path/Default/Bookmarks"
'/tmp/bookmarks/e9778031e907cf8d2d196be3319ac24d.json' -> '/Users/christian/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks'
~ $ <"$path/Default/Bookmarks" jq  .checksum 
"e9778031e907cf8d2d196be3319ac24d"
``
```

Comment: Why remove my obvious exasperation, @DaveM? It adds context to the answer, and hopefully acts as a negative reinforcer for the next junior engineer that reads it. Hiding the emotional cues from a response does a disservice to to people operating in a real world environment, where frustration is a common currency.